# OLEDBConnection.Open() External table is not in the expected format

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, oledbconnection

I've literally done everything I've searched for on here the past 2 days just to get my .xlsx Excel file to upload into a DataTable and be used as my RadGrid DataSource.  Here is my code...

```
  private void ImportToGrid(string filePath, string hasHeaderRow)
    {
        string connectionString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR={1}';", filePath, hasHeaderRow);

        using (OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand excelCommand = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                excelConnection.Open();
                //Get the SheetName
                DataTable dtExcelSchema = new DataTable();
                dtExcelSchema = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                string sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

                excelCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "]";
                excelCommand.Connection = excelConnection;

                using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    oda.SelectCommand = excelCommand;
                    oda.Fill(dt);
                    rgCalendarYear.DataSource = dt;
                    rgCalendarYear.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

...I was able to convert the Excel file from a ".xlsx" to a ".xls", and everything works when I upload the file, but I need the ".xlsx" file to work.

I've added an @ symbol before the connectionString, I installed Access Database Engine 2010, Access 2010 Runtime, I've changed the connectionString all kinds of different ways (including IMEX=1, IMEX=0, Excel 8.0, Excel 12.0 Xml and everything else that is in other solutions.)  No matter what I do, I just keep getting "External table is not in the expected format." on my ".xlsx" file when it hits "excelConnection.Open();".  Again, ".xls" works just fine, but ".xlsx" does not.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Please, is there anything I'm overlooking?  No 3rd party suggestions, please.

EDIT: I have now found that if I have the ".xlsx" file open when I try the upload, it works as well.  Now, I just need it to work without the file to be open.